# How to run a war file in cronetab

Tags: java, cron

I have a Java project which gives me output based on user's request in the front end.

The output is like it will give me the list of devices from each and every server(based on click of a radio button).

Now I need to set up a crontab job which will run at a particular time and it will automatically get the output of all the servers without user's request.

Can anyone give me an approach as how I need to tune my program so that it will automatically give the list of all devices.?

Also do I have to create a war file and deploy that in crone tab to run the daily job?

Comment: WAR files are Web ARchives, meant to run inside a Web Container (think Tomcat, JBOSS, etc) - probably you want an executable JAR file which you can run from the command line and schedule it via CRON

Comment: Thanks. Can I export my java project as jar file and then run it via command line and schedule it?

Comment: Yes, there are a few steps to take but it is doable.  See http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse

Comment: Can I use quartz scheduler or cron tab for Java projects? I am new to both and would like to know which one is an easier method so that I can implement.

Comment: They are both slightly better for different purposes.  Depends on your needs. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478150/quartz-scheduler-vs-setting-up-cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAR files are Web ARchives, meant to run inside a Web Container (think Tomcat, JBOSS, etc) - probably you want an executable JAR file.  You are probably thinking of Java ARchive (JAR) files.

I would first create an executable JAR file and then schedule it as a CRON job to run at the frequency you wish.

1. [How to create an executable JAR file](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)
2. [How to setup a CRON
   job](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)