# Run batch automatically at dawn

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch, batch-processing, jobs

I have created a complete and functional batch process, which I run manually running a Launcher.java that has a main method and executes the job I defined (this job I defined it in an xml and I pass it as arguments to my main), That works perfectly well, now I'm looking to take it to production and for that I need to configure that process to run every day at one in the morning in Spain, how can I do that? This is my Launcher (if I right-click run as-> java application, it works fine but how do I make a batch run just as I need it?)

```
 public final class Launcher {

private static final String LOG_DECORATOR = "****************************************.";
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("batch");
private static final Long MIL = 1000L;

private Launcher(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
    LOG.info(" INICIO DEL PROCESO ");
    LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);

    LOG.info("Cargando datos de configuracion");

    final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);

    final PropertyFacade property = applicationContext.getBean(PropertyFacade.class);
    Assert.notNull(property, "Datos de configuracion no cargados correctamente");
    final String entorno = property.property("entorno");
    LOG.info("Entorno: ".concat(entorno));
    final JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
    final Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean("job");
    long tiempoComenzar;
    long tiempoTerminar;
    tiempoComenzar = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        LOG.info("Job Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        LOG.info("Job completed");
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobParametersInvalidException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobRestartException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    }finally {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).close();
        tiempoTerminar = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long tiempoDedicado = (tiempoTerminar - tiempoComenzar) / MIL;
        LOG.info(
                "Fin. Tiempo dedicado a la consulta: ".concat(String.valueOf(tiempoDedicado)).concat(" segundos."));
        LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
        LOG.info(" FIN DEL PROCESO ");
        LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
    }

}
```

}

This is the Job

[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsIEQ.png)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your code is not relevant to the question, what *is* relevant is: on which operating system your code run ? does it have a builtin task-scheduler ? (like cron for example)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Run on Windows, no, I do not know about the programmer of tasks that is what I am trying to understand or know how to do, the job executes 3 steps that are defined in three classes. Java (3task)

Comment: Use Quartz. it sets up a scheduler similar to cron. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: On Windows you can use the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) to execute your app at specific times.

Answer (score 0):

Job scheduling is a separate concern & you can choose your options depending on what kind of deployment model you have.

1.If your output is a simple jar file that needs to run as standalone application, you can schedule it on UNIX* systems with as simple tool as `cron`.

You can go on with more profession tools like quartz etc as mentioned in few comments.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478150/quartz-scheduler-vs-setting-up-cron) are more discussions.

2.If you are deploying in some kind of server, then you can simply write your own scheduler using `@Scheduled` annotation. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) is detailed documentation and this kind of scheduling provides few options like - cron like expression, fixed delay etc.

I have a job deployed in Weblogic where I use option # 2. You will need your job launching logic to be written in this `@Scheduled` method using `JobLauncher`. I am using a cron expression and have externalized that cron expression through properties. Once your app is deployed & up, this scheduling will automatically kick off your jobs.

Hope it helps !!